# How to modify a Transform stream in Node.js whose parameters are part of the source stream

Tags: node.js, stream

Say I have a transform stream that is created with a single parameter - e.g. `createTransform(a)`.

It expects to read from a stream, do its work, and output a transformed stream. But I have a situation where the parameter `a` is the first x bytes of the source stream. x is always fixed and known.

How can I create my own transform stream that expects a stream with `a` as the first x bytes?

i.e. original scenario:

`source.pipe(createTransform(a)).pipe(destination)`

desired scenario:

`sourceWithAPrepended.pipe(createTransformReadingA()).pipe(destination)`

I'm afraid I've been unable to work out how to even approach this. Assume that `createTransform` is a black box, and I want to create the function `createTransformReadingA`

Many thanks for any guidance